# CakePHP Attachment component problem

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, attachment

I am trying to use the Attachment component (seen [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tutec/2010/01/05/file-upload-and-thumbnail-component)). I followed the instructions and added this to my view:

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Event', array('type' => 'file'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->file('image_attach'); ?>
```

Then added this into my controller's `add` function:

```
$this->data['Event']['image'] = $this->Attachment->upload($this->data['Event']['image_attach']);
```

I also declared this at the top of my controller class:

```
var $components = array('Attachment' => array(
    'photos_dir' => 'events'
));
```

When the form is submitted, I have it `var_dump`'ing  my `data` variable to see what's being added. But before that happens, I get this error.

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: event [APP/controllers/components/attachment.php, line 67]
```

I've tried looking in the component's file, and all I can tell is it's trying to find an index that is the name of my model in the array I pass through. But, I already figured that out from the error above.

I just want to know if I've done something wrong, or what might be causing this to happen, whether it's my fault or the component's?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm after reading the component... it seems to me that you need to call the `upload()` method like this:

```
$this->Attachment->upload($this->data['Event'],'image_attach');
```

Good Luck!